# Using netsh advfirewall to block URLs in Windows

Tags: firewall, iptables, windows-firewall, netsh, ipfw

I know that Windows allow blocking IP addresses through netsh like so:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block some stuff" dir=in action=block remoteip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx enable=yes`

But is there any way to use netsh (or is there any other Windows utility) to block URLs like how ipfw and iptables allows? I know there's wipfw, but I'd like to use something built in if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nslookup to resolve dns/ip of the url and block that ip using netsh.
Or, you may add an exception in hosts file in Windows.